# Understanding multiple induction in the proof of Ramsey's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, induction, ramsey-theory

I am a graduate student and we are having a course on discrete mathematics.In the second class,we were taught Ramsey's theorem in its most general form:

**Theorem**

Given positive integers $k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r$,there exists a natural number $n=n(k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r)$ such that for any $r$-coloring of $\binom{[n]}{k}$ ,the set of all $k$-subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,...,n\}$ by colours $c_1,c_2,...,c_r$ there exists $i\in \{1,2,...,r\}$ such that there exists an $\ell_i$-subset $S$ all of whose $k$ subsets are of colour $c_i$.[The smallest $n$ satisfying the theorem is denoted by $R(k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r)$]

I am not comfortable with the proof of this theorem which uses multiple induction.The proof is as follows:

For $k=1$, we have to look at $1$-subsets of $[n]$ which are $n$ singletons.Take $n=\ell_1+...+\ell_r-r+1$ and by generalized pigeonhole principle we are done.
Now assume that $R(k-1,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r)$ extsts for any $\ell_i$.

Now for any $k$,
If $\ell_i=k$  for all $i$,then we are done.Also if some $\ell_i<k$ then we are done.

Now assuming that the numbers $a_i=R(k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_i-1,...,\ell_r)$ exist we have to show that $R(k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r)$ exists.The proof ends by showing that $n=1+R(k,r,a_1,...,a_r)$ works for $k,r,\ell_1,...,\ell_r$.

Now I am not sure how we are able to conclude by showing this.For simple induction,if we know that a statement $P(n)$ is true for $n=1$ and if we know that $P(k)$ is true $\implies P(k+1)$ is also true,then it is certain that $P(2)$ is true as $P(1)$ is true,$P(3)$ is true as $P(2)$ is true and so on,thus for all $n\in \mathbb N$ the statement $P(n)$ is true.

But here I do not follow the logic and I also do not follow which quantity is varying and which is fixed.Can someone please write the induction hypothesis and its conclusion for this multiple induction and explain why it works,like on which set are we doing induction and what is our $P$ statement here and on which variable am I doing induction?

Comment: Well, if nothing else, you seem to have some serious typos in the proof: my guess is that what you should actually be saying to prove that $R(k,r,\ell_1,\dots,\ell_r)$ exists is the following: suppose that you know that $R(k-1,r,b_1,\dots,b_r)$ exists for every $b_1,\dots, b_r$ **and** that $a_i:=R(k,r,\ell_1, \dots,\ell_i-1,\dots, \ell_r)$ exists for every $i$. Then, you can prove that $1+R(k-1,r,a_1,\dots,a_r)$ works. Can you see how to prove the claim by multiple induction now?

Comment: @Leo163 I think it is indented multiple induction,for $k=1$ it is true.Now assume that $R(k-1,r,b_1,...,b_r)$ exists for all $b_i$,if we could show that $R(k,r,b_1,...,b_r)$ exists for all $b_i$ we are done.Now $k$ is fixed and we show that $R(k,r,k,...,k)$ exists which is the base case and now assume that $R(k,r,l_1,...,l_i-1,...,l_r)$ exist and show that $R(k,r,l_1,....,l_r)$ exists.

Comment: Indeed. You just have to combine the hypotheses you have in order to prove the last claim.